# Get-ChildItem does not Fetch Files when Used a Variable for Drive Letter

Tags: powershell, find, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, get-childitem

Following code Works:
Get-ChildItem "C:\" -recurse -include *.dll

But the following code DOES NOT WORK when the drive is replaced with a variable containing the string.

> $temp = "C:";
>   Get-ChildItem "$temp" -recurse -include *.dll.

Any Clue what might be the issue??

Comment: Couldn't reproduce using the posted code. Try running just this line in a new powershell session. If it runs, the problem is something else. Otherwise it could be some broken code in PS profile script.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved with the following:
$temp = "C:"; 
Get-ChildItem $temp -recurse -include *.dll

Answer (score 0):

It's work try this :

```
$temp = "C:\Program Files"
$DllDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path $temp -Recurse -Include *.dll
$DllDirectory
```